Is B(p) V B(~p) an instance of LEM in doxastic logic?
So in classical logic either p is T or p is F. But is it same in doxastic logic, ie, is B(p) V B(~p) an instance of LEM?
And the second issue, is it equivalent to B(p) V ~B(p)?

In general, not-something(p) is not the same as something(not-p).

think of the empty acessibility relation

B(p) v ¬B(p) is an ordinary example of LEM. B(p) v B(¬p) means something different and is implausible, since it rules out being indifferent to some proposition p and neither believing it nor disbelieving it.

<>  No, in  classical logic either P is given or ~P is given.  Every proposition is true or false by definition, just classically we postulate that we unconditionally have access to which it is.

@JulioDiEgidio I don’t understand what you mean. What is wrong with the OP’s statement?
